# Redmine on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, redmine

I am trying to deploy a Redmine on Heroku but it does not work

I get this error message

```
 You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
   your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
   updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
   You have added to the Gemfile:
   * capybara (~> 2.1.0)
   * selenium-webdriver
   * database_cleaner
   Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
   your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
   updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

   You have added to the Gemfile:
   * capybara (~> 2.1.0)
   * selenium-webdriver
   * database_cleaner
!
!     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
!

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I keep doing

```
bundle install
```

but it does not change anything. I also tried deleting the Gemfile.lock and run bundle install again but no success

Comment: And you're committing the Gemfile.lock to your git repo before pushing?

Comment: Yes. To begin with it was mentioned in Gitignore but I removed that line

Comment: recheck it again in `gitk` or other git tools that you pushed `Gemfile.lock` to repository and Heroku takes code from it.

Comment: Do you have RAILS_ENV or RACK_ENV set to "development" on Heroku? Check with `heroku config -a <app_name>`

Comment: It says <app_name> has no config vars

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. It happens if you use a lower ruby version than 1.9.3 locally when bundle install, and Heroku uses 2.0.0

> if RUBY_VERSION >= '1.9.3'
>
> ```
> gem "capybara", "~> 2.1.0"
> gem "selenium-webdriver"
> ```
>
> end

so you either update your ruby version or you just delete this part from the Gemfile.

I hope this works for you too.